# How to de-compile Java classes using jadretro

Tags: java

I downloaded [jadretro software](http://jadretro.sourceforge.net/) that helps me to de-compile my Java class files.

When I try to de-compile, then I am not getting the source code for my class files.

Here is the command that I ran:

```
D:\jadretro>jadretro.exe D:\myclasses\

Done.
```

I have kept some class files under `myclasses` folder, when I try to run the `jadretro` then it says `done`, but I don't see any Java code generated in my folder.

Please help me how to use jadretro`?

`Edit:`

Based on response for my post, I have tried these options:

```
D:\jadretro>jadretro.exe D:\myclasses\Hello.class

Done.

D:\jadretro>jadretro.exe D:\myclasses\*.class

Done.
```

Even then the classes or not de-compiled.

Comment: Well the sample documentation would suggest that you should be running `jadretro.exe d:\myclasses\*.class`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot Jon for replying, I tried it, but still the file is not de-compiled. Updated my post with its details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that it needs this:

`D:\jadretro>jadretro.exe D:\myclasses\SomeClassName.class`

Try it, see if it helps.

Try also:

`D:\jadretro>jadretro.exe D:\myclasses\*.class`

**UPDATE**

OK, I checked this tool myself.

See what the documentation says:

> JadRetro is a command-line utility that could help You to successfully
>   decompile Java classes created by the modern Java compilers (of Java
>   1.4, Java 1.5 or later).
>
> JadRetro operates by transforming the specified Java class files (if
>   needed) into ones which could be processed correctly by an old Java
>   decompiler (designed to work with classes of Java 1.3 or earlier).
>
> JadRetro is not a decompiler itself, it is a class transformer helping
>   some old (but good) Java decompilers to convert more class files
>   and/or generate more correct source code.

Then I ran it on my machine on some .class files which I have.

```
c:\Programs\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\TEST\bin>cd \programs\jadretro

c:\Programs\jadretro>jadretro.exe  c:\Programs\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\TEST\bin\*.class
Class transformed: BookType
Class transformed: Dummy
Class transformed: Helloworld$1$HelloComponent
Class transformed: Helloworld
Class transformed: Test
Class transformed: Test31
Done.
```

Then I went into my bin folder and checked these class files,
they have all been modified a few secounds ago
(apparently by the jadretro tool which I ran).

[image: Files Modified by Jadretro]

So this tool is not decompiling the classes, it is just transforming
them to some old Java bytecode format. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried both the approaches, but still the file is not de-compiled. I have also updated my post with the details.

Comment: What I noticed though is that this tool didn't update all files that were present in my bin folder "c:\Programs\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64\workspace\TEST\bin\".

Comment: All in all, I don't know why you need this tool, but I would probably try not to use it. Not really sure what it does exactly and what guarantees exactly it gives you. "Disclaimer: You use this software at your own risk."

Comment: Thanks Peter for taking time and checking the tool. I realized that I cannot use this tool for de-compiling class files based on your comments. Thanks a lot :)